# Rotating Canvas Without Rotating Images - Seeking a Solution for Landscape Images and Video Letterboxed in a Portrait Layout

Tags: adobe-premiere

I am creating a slideshow project in Adobe Premiere Pro and encountered a problem. The canvas/frame is in a portrait orientation, while the images and videos in the project retain landscaping format. The width of the canvas/frame constrains the media and leaves large vacant areas above and below the images and video. I would like to learn how to rotate the canvas into a landscape orientation to reduce the letterboxing effect caused by the mismatched content and frame orientations.

I have explored matching frame rates (video2brain.com/en/lessons/changing-a-sequence-to-match-a-clip) and scaling to frame size without success.

Below is a screen capture illustrating the issue. Please observe the movie preview pane in the top right corner for the letterboxing (from the video preview, the slideshow image is being cropped by the portrait-oriented frame):

[image]

This is the original image (notice the left and right cropping of the image in the above slideshow preview):

[image]

I appreciate suggestions for learning to solve this challenge.

Comment: Why don't you just change canvas size and format in its properties? It's YOU who defines the frame orientation, not the software.

Comment: @Alex.S Yes, changing the canvas size resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @Alex.S, changing the canvas size resolves the issue. The setting is located by going to the Sequence tab and choosing Sequence Settings.

Sequence -> Sequence Settings

In the video section in the settings panel, the Frame Size can be adjusted. For the issue mentioned in the question, switching the horizontal size for the vertical size positioned the canvas in the desired landscape format.

After setting the canvas, some images may not have uniform letterboxing (the black "bars" beyond the dimensions of the image or video content). To fix this,

1) select every image or video clip in the timeline

2) right click on the timeline

3) select "Scale to Frame Size"